# Select a Kendo Tab after a page refresh

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How do I select a kendo tab based on the completion of an event on a page?

I have a kendo ui tabstrip with 5 tabs, on the 5th tab (index 4) I have an upload control that fires an onComplete event when its done with it's upload. At that time, I would like to refresh the page and bring the focus back to the 5th tab by selecting it.

The code:

```
    function onImageComplete(e) {

    var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    tabstrip.select(4);

    location.reload(true);
}
```

The code to select the tab desired works fine in my document ready function, but of course on document ready, I want the first tab to display. I only want the fifth tab after an event on tab 5.

Thanks

*(any script advice is welcome)*

Comment: why do you refresh the page?

Comment: By the way I couldn't understand your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to reload the page, then instead of using `location.refresh` use `window.location`, passing the URL of the current page. This time add a query string parameter, something like `&selectTabIndex={index of tab to be selected}`.

Within `$(document).ready()` check for that query string using something like the `getParameterByName` function detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and then use the kendo tabstrip `select()` function, passing in the value of the query string, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectTabIndex = getParameterByName('selectTab');

  if (selectTabIndex != null) {
    var tabStrip = $('#tabStrip').getKendoTabStrip();
    tabStrip.select(selectTabIndex);
  }
});
```